# Save Print Job in Queue as PDF

Tags: windows, pdf, printing, printer

I am trying to print coupons from a coupon website that only allow you to print the coupons once, and of course whenever I want the printer to work the best, the print job gets stuck in the queue. Because I will lose the print job if I use `net stop spooler` and `net start spooler`, I would like to save the queued print job as a PDF file so that I can clear the queue and then trying printing the PDF. Is this possible? I have gone to the `C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS` folder and copied a file named `FP00000.spl` from there. In the same folder, there was a file named `FP00000.SHD` that I wanted to copy, but I couldn't because it was being used by the print spooler. What can I do with the `spl` file to get the PDF file that I want? I have tried uploading the file to Google Cloud Print, but it does not work.

Comment: Why not just ALWAYS print things to the PDF queue?  Then print any you desire as a paper copy afterwards.  Hmmmm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't save the print job as a pdf. Print Queues don't work like that. Depending on when your spooler crashes/hangs, the files may not even be what you want.

The **SHD** filetype tells Windows/Printer what the job settings are for that particular print job.
The **SPL** filetype is a file that tells Windows/Printer how to draw out what you sent in. This is the file that we actually care about.

**SPL** is unfortunately not an entirely open protocol. Microsoft does publish it's *standard* from time to time but it can't be relied on not to change. As such, not too many programs exist to deal with it.

You can save print queue jobs. If you open up the *Properties* dialog box for your printer, you can navigate into the *advanced* tab and enable *keep printed documents*. By doing so, it will keep the job in the spooler folder and you can access them later.

If you want to "*print*" a document out as a pdf you can either use [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/intl/en-CA/chrome/browser/) and choose the option *save to pdf* or you can install a "*fake*" printer queue that you can send jobs to like a normal printer. One option for the latter would be a program like [CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/Products/CutePDF/writer.asp).

Now, to recover from your SPL file. It's not entirely hopeless, there are a few programs that exist to read from these files. I recommend a program called [SPLViewer](http://www.lvbprint.de/html/splviewer1.html). The website is in German but the tool works very well. Can export/print from it.